# always hiding a button after clicking on it using php and css

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have this php code which hide the download button after clicking on it one time by changing the ID from 0 to 1 .. after that if another time the user signed in , it removes the button using a simple css hide code.

here is my code :

```
<?php

        $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  scode   WHERE updated= 1 and coden ='$username'");
if ($_POST[downloadTheFile]== "downloadTheFile")
{
$upd_art = "update  scode  set downloaded='".$_POST[t11] ."' where id='$_SESSION[userid]'";
      mysql_query($upd_art) or die(mysql_error());
}

if($row['downloaded']==1)
{
echo "<style>
.thedownloadbutton {display:none;}
</style>";
}

    ?>
<form class="thedownloadbutton" method="get" action="<? echo '../download/'.$item_downloadlink .'.zip' ;  ?>">
<button type="submit" name="downloadTheFile" value="downloadTheFile">Download </button>
<input name="t11"  type="hidden" size="2" value="1">
</form>
```

*(just for clarifying: updated =1 is a field that'll open the download page.. if the updated =1 then there is a download page )*

I don't know why it doesn't work ..
can you help me please and till me which part is the wrong part ?
I know it's a bad way to hide an element using css , is there another suggestion ?

Comment: $_POST[downloadTheFile] should be $_POST['downloadTheFile']

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` that will show you errors in code. Something you may not be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so there were some problems in this code .. it wasn't professional at all  so I used this new code which has a button that update the number from 0 to 1 on the database
*(that will tell the download button to not show after that)* 
 then shows the download button

```
<?

$res = mysql_query("SELECT downloaded FROM scode WHERE id='$_SESSION[userid]'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
// echo $row['downloaded'];
echo '<br>';
?>
<form method="POST" action=''>
<?
if($row['downloaded'] ==='0')
{
echo "<input type='submit' name='button1' value='click to show the download link' onclick ='validatea(); return false;' />";


//echo '<button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="downloadTheFile" value="downloadTheFile">Download </button>';

?>
</form>

<?
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) 
{ 


        ?> <form class="aaa" method="POST" action="<? echo "../download/".$item_downloadlink .".zip" ;  ?>"> 
        <? ;
        ?> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='download' onclick ='validate(); return false;' /> <? ;
        echo"</form>";

   $upd_art = "update  scode  set downloaded='1' where id='$_SESSION[userid]'";
      mysql_query($upd_art) or die(mysql_error());
} 
}
else {
    echo "you already downloaded the file , if you have any problem please contact us";
    echo"<br>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[downloadTheFile]` should be `$_POST['downloadTheFile']`

```
if($row['downloaded']!=1)
{
echo '<button type="submit" name="downloadTheFile" value="downloadTheFile">Download </button>';
}
```

Comment: thank you, this really helped me .. but there was a problem in the method .. the action didn't changed the number in the database .. I'll post my answer in a new comment :)